# catch R tryCatch() out of bounds exception in order to ignore execption

Tags: exception, try-catch-finally

Problem:

R tryCatch() needed to handle known error.

I am working with a word vector matrix to run the the vector word location. I am seeking to add a R tryCatch() to handle, or catch this subscript out of bounds. It is expected behavior for the word search.
What is the exact method to catch, to ignore, an exception in R? What exception code should I use to catch out of bounds?

For example:

```
word1 = 'This'
word2 = 'Happy'
```

This combination would NOT be expected to match in this contextual search inside the word vector. So subscript out of bounds indicates that this match does not exist.

Code:

```
'''
    word_vectors[word1, , drop=FALSE] + word_vectors[word2, , drop=FALSE]
'''
```

Error Message:

```
'''
run_glove_search(word1, word2, word_vectors)
Error in word_vectors[word1, , drop = FALSE] : subscript out of bounds
> View(word_vectors)
'''
```

The error is due to the subscript out of bounds, which IS EXPECTED on word combinations that do not  match. Therefore, this is expected beharior.

Data example:
Note: the word matrix is a large matrix 75800, so I only show 1 row of statistics example

```
'''
This    0.175438308 0.1229126933    -0.792327086    -0.698233553    0.407953490 0.362040523 0.258780885 0.352198675 -0.170637061    -0.512016098    0.408881291 -0.0866425339   0.0510299517    -0.150036589    0.002336813 0.390699917 -0.635815296    -0.295312958
'''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code solution:
TryCatch() with error = function(e) and do nothing, since I know and expect that this error will occur, so I can just assign NULL to the e of function(e) since I do not need any error message.

```
  tryCatch({
    gws <- word_vectors[word1, , drop=FALSE] + word_vectors[word2, , drop=FALSE]
    cos_sim = sim2(x = word_vectors, y = gws, method = "cosine", norm = "l2")
    head(sort(cos_sim[,1], decreasing = TRUE), 7)
    },
    error = function(e){e=NULL}
  )
```